# BGE Record gameplay?

Tags: game-engine

Is there any way to simply record the gameplay within BGE? Im not using animation, I just want to record myself moving the camera around.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Blender but rather methods for recording gameplay

Comment: It is about the BGE (and correctly tagged).

Comment: Do you want to record the camera motion (the path) or do you want to record the video (what you see)?

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ I think this could be on topic, there fore am reopening

Comment: @GiantCowFilms In the question's current state, it is not on topic as it explicitly states they want to record gameplay. If the OP updates it, then we can re-open. All off-topic questions **could** under some circumstances be on topic :/

Comment: May you please describe how you plan to do this without animation?

Comment: Okay, I was simply wondering if there was a way to do this without animating the camera. For example, if BGE had an internal feature that allows you to record what you see when you press 'p'.

Comment: So you guess you want to record the output to video. No, there is no build-in function to do that. But you can use an external screen recorder as with other games.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a *Record Animation* function:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/physics/introduction.html